# Метка кластера для простого объекта

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Не могу понять, как обычной метке, передаваемой в json в массиве `FeatureCollection`, задать метку кластера? Просто `'preset' => 'islands#redClusterIcons'` не помогает, метка становится стандартной.

Comment: А где код???????

Comment: А какой тут код, простой вопрос - как задать метке иконку кластера.

Answer (score 2):

можно использовать iconLayout 'default#imageWithContent' и в свойство imageHref просто написать данные для иконки кластера, вот пример: https://jsfiddle.net/7g054a3b/

```
ymaps.ready(function () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
            zoom: 9
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),

        // Создаём макет содержимого.
        MyIconContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
            '<div style="color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold;">$[properties.iconContent]</div>'
        ),

        myPlacemarkWithContent = new ymaps.Placemark([55.661574, 37.573856], {
            hintContent: 'Собственный значок метки с контентом',
            balloonContent: 'А эта — новогодняя',
            iconContent: '12'
        }, {
            // Опции.
            // Необходимо указать данный тип макета.
            iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',
            // Своё изображение иконки метки.
            iconImageHref: 'data:image/png;base64,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',
            // Размеры метки.
            iconImageSize: [48, 48],
            // Смещение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно
            // её "ножки" (точки привязки).
            iconImageOffset: [-24, -24],
            // Смещение слоя с содержимым относительно слоя с картинкой.
            iconContentOffset: [15, 15],
            // Макет содержимого.
            iconContentLayout: MyIconContentLayout
        });

    myMap.geoObjects
        .add(myPlacemarkWithContent);
});
```